# Unable to send emails using nodemailer without authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I need to send emails from my application for any exceptions, so I am using nodemailer for that but I cannot provide username and password for the account and without which It is not letting me send any emails. Any solutions? This is how my code looks as of now:

```
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';

//Create reusable transport object using the SMTP transport
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp-mail.outlook.com',
    port: 587,
    secureConnection: false,
    requireTLS: true,
    tls: {
        // do not fail on invalid certs
        rejectUnauthorized: false
      }
});


module.exports = function sendEmail(to, subject, message) {
    let mailOptions = {
        from: '********',
        to,
        subject,
        html: message
    };
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

    });
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't quite know about nodemailer, but with [sendmail](https://github.com/guileen/node-sendmail), you can send emails without a SMTP server, but for that to work you have to use dkim authentication, for short your email must be sent from the same domain as the email you're trying to send, take a look at this [article](https://blog.returnpath.com/how-to-explain-dkim-in-plain-english-2/), hope that helps.